# How to add right bar in proof

Tags: mdframed, polyglossia, amsthm

when i use `mdframed` the right bar is proof double line:

```
    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch,amsthm,xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%select languages & fonts ==================================
\makeatletter
 \xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}{}{}{} % same font 
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries\proofnameformat}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofnameformat}{}
\makeatother
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=algeria]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\mdfdefinestyle{my}{
 hidealllines=true,
  rightline=true,
  innerleftmargin=10pt,
  innerrightmargin=10pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
 % middlelinewidth=1pt,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=my]{proof}% use the new theorem style
% declare a new theorem style
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below 
{\color{black}}% Body font\itshape
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries\color{blue}}% Theorem head font
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head 
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{مبرهنة}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{خاصية}[section]
\newtheorem{exm}{مثال}
\newtheorem{rem}{ملاحظة}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
$a$
عدد حقيقي موجب.\\
 نسمي الجذر التربيعي للعدد الحقيقي   العدد الحقيقي الموجب الذي مربعه يساوي  $ a $ ونرمزه إليه
  $ \sqrt{a}$.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
بلبل\\
يسي
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry,I have absolutelely no problem compliling with `xelatex`.

Comment: The problem here -@Bernard -is how two remove the second line in proof, but in another language it exists one line.

Comment: I have only one with the code you posted.

Comment: ُُExcuse me, i don't  understand what you mean?

Comment: If I understand well your question, your proof environment results in a double bar on the right. I was saying that with your code, I obtain a single bar (on the right).

Comment: When i comment \setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=algeria]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri} , i get single bar, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41575/discussion-between-hb-khaled-and-bernard).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the OP's example so I'm voting to close